# Does semi-frozen vetegable have less nutrients?

Tags: freezing, vegetables, refrigerator

I stored green vegetables for salad such as red beet, celery, kale, etc in the refrigerator for 3~5 days and found that they are kind of 'semi' frozen. They are a little hard than the fresh status but not completely frozen.
I wonder whether this 'semi-freezing' may reduce nutrition in the vegetable.
They are just for me, so the taste does not really matter now.

Comment: Questions which revolve purely around nutritional information are off-topic for SA.

Comment: I better question is probably if they are still palatable. I don't expect there is any significant nutritional difference, but vegetables are very sensitive to freezing, I'd expect most are no longer very pleasant for uncooked use.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects here:

1. Does this destroy any nutrients?
2. Does this make nutrients less available for absorption after consumption?

I’m not aware of any major nutrients that are harmed by being frozen.

As for the second one, it’s actually the opposite.  Freezing damages cell walls which means that their contents leak out.  This actually makes it easier for your body to extract nutrients from the food.

If you chew your food thoroughly or had planned to put the food through a blender, you might not see a significant difference.